# Angular.js(SPA) loading times issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

I have a website which is built with Angular.js. I’m having issues with a slow loading time (obviously), especially from users in countries that have slow internet connections. Even for some users, the page is not loaded at all. How can I improve the initial loading times?

Comment: In all the usual ways in which loading times are improved in traditional sites too: minify resources, bundle resources to reduce number of HTTP requests, use a CDN and caching etc.

Comment: Use yslow tool to analyze which will provide suggestion something like this https://efficientuser.wordpress.com/2015/09/04/yslows-performance-analysis/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the minified versions of the libraries and use minification for your .js and .css files. Enable gzip compression on the server and use a CDN for content distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Is it related to the Angular.js library or the page load speed parameters like "caching" or "server speed"? What I advice you to use [google page speed analyser](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) that gives you clear tips to speed-up your page.

If the pages are loaded because of the slow process of the Angular.JS than you should dig into your code and find the performance bottle-necks and then start trying to figure out what can be better than that solution.

I hope these help.